# How to encrypte and decrypte laravel 5.4.6 class object

Tags: php, laravel, encryption

How can I encrypte and decrypte of class object, store it into database. Actually I want to secure my database that if anyone stole it then not able to read it.

```
   Employee Controller


   $employee = new Employee();
   $employee->name = $request->get('name');
   $employee->code = $request->get('code');
   $employee->email = $request->get('email');
   $employee->cell = $request->get('cell');
   $employee->password = $request->get('password');
```

Here I want to encrypte the $employee object and store it into database and also want to decrypte it to view it again. Please guide me

Answer (score 0):

Hi Amir you are using laravel 5.4 there is helper method available.

```
$employee = new Employee();
$employee->name = encrypt( $request->get('name'));
$employee->code = encrypt($request->get('code'));
$employee->email = encrypt($request->get('email'));
$employee->cell = encrypt($request->get('cell'));
$employee->password = encrypt($request->get('password'));
```

thats it. your complete row is encrypted. make sure length varchar in database is greater than 100. other wise it will not be decrypted when you need it.

if you want to decrypt simply

```
decrypt($employee->name); // it will return string
```